# how to separate the values in min() predicate prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I have a predicate like

```
cheapest(X,Y,T):-
    findall([Ci,Cj],trip_cost(X,Y,[Ci,Cj]),K),
    aggregate_all(min(A,B), 
       member([B,A], K), 
       T).
```

It gives the result like

```
min(8,[a,b,m])
```

I want to make it work with predicate like

```
cheapest(X,Y,T,C):-
        findall([Ci,Cj],trip_cost(X,Y,[Ci,Cj]),K),
        aggregate_all(min(A,B), 
           member([B,A], K), 
           T).
```

and want result like

```
T=[a,b,m]
C=8
```

Comment: Do you have any knowledgebase? Include that also here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cheapest(X,Y,T,C):-
    cheapest(X,Y,min(C,T)).
```

I can't test it yet since there is no knowledgebase.

Or similar without the need of `cheapest/3`:

```
cheapest(X,Y,T,C):-
    findall([Ci,Cj],trip_cost(X,Y,[Ci,Cj]),K),
    aggregate_all(min(A,B), 
       member([B,A], K), 
       TT),
    TT = min(C,T).
```